# 403 forbidden when I send a POST request (axios) on specific API

Tags: node.js, https, axios, tls1.2, akamai

Good evening everyone. I've been playing with HTTPs request for a while and I've been reading the axios documentation. I've been trying to send a request to a specific API (Zalando) but I got struck with 403 forbidden. Modules like puppeteer and chromium works fine because they do sit in a web browser and so they don't get easily detected by Akamai. Here below is the code I'm using. I've been doing this ONLY for educational purpose. Feel free to comment. Have a nice day all.

```
    const axios = require('axios')
  
    const params = [{
        id: "e7f9dfd05f6b992d05ec8d79803ce6a6bcfb0a10972d4d9731c6b94f6ec75033",
        variables: {
            addToCartInput: {
                productId: "PU111A0P1-C110035000",
                clientMutationId: "addToCartMutation"
            }
        }
    }]

    const instance = axios.create({
        withCredentials: true,
        baseURL: 'https://www.zalando.it'
     })

    instance.post('/api/graphql/add-to-cart/', params, {
        headers: {
            'accept': '*/*',
            'content-Type': 'application/json',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36',
            
        }, 
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
   }
}
```

`Response: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403]`

Comment: If you get an HTTP 403 that means at least the TLS channel was establishes successful, client detection by Akamai and similar nowadays usually base on TLS fingerprinting. If such a system reject you you don't even get an HTTP response code, because the TLS channel is never established. Therefore it is more likely that your request is the problem.  If you have a working request in a different client redirect both through a proxy like Mitmproxy or Fiddler and compare the requests from both clients.

Comment: Hi! I've tried using this https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/tls-fingerprinting-node-js/ . TLS fingerprints seems to work for GET request on Zalando API and not POST. Let me know if I need also to set specific headers. I've been working for some hours and I get 403 or DNS Failure. I don't know if I need to establish a DNS server myself.
I've used axios, node-fetch, superagent at the moment to see if there's a difference but is the same 403 error.